# update_attributes(:a => [" "]) should not handle by validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchrest

I have the code as below, as I understand, it only handles when a.blank? is true. But ["  "].blank? is false. Why it cannot pass validation

```
class Demo < CouchRest::Model::Base
  collection_of :subdemos
  validate :ensure_subdemos

  def ensure_subdemos
    errors.add(:demo, "must include subdemos.") if subdemos.blank?
  end 
end
```

if I do `demo.update_attributes(:subdemo_ids => ["     "])`, why it cannot pass validation?? Can anyone go through the process for me??

Comment: Because `.blank?` takes into account whitespace. That's why it returns **false**.

Comment: @nersoh Thanks for the answer. I tried on rails console
    `[4] pry(main)> ["     "].blank?   => false`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use actual IDs. White space is blank:

```
-> % rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.3)

Frame number: 0/5
[1] pry(main)> "     ".blank?
true
[2] pry(main)>
```

If you add data there it should pass validation:

```
demo.update_attributes(:subdemo_ids => [1,2,3])
```

If you want to allow white space or an empty array, try:

```
def ensure_subdemos
  errors.add(:demo, "must include subdemos.") if subdemos.nil?
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. ` "     ".blank?` is true. But what I past is `["     "].blank?` this is false.

Comment: `subdemo_ids` is expected to be an array of IDs, not empty strings. An empry string should by ignored and then it becomes `[]`, and `[].blank? == true`. You need to pass *actual* IDs, not an empty string. The code you have is rightly failing validation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To make sure I understand, you mean rails will ignore empty string as id when I pass `:subdemo_ids => ["     "]`, so rails will regard it as `:subdemo_ids => []`???